# How to call a user form from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba

The code am writing here is having reference in `book1.xlsx` (when I click book1 it should show me the user form) and am calling the user form from `book2.xlsx` (where I have created the user form)

The code written in `book2.xlsx` is

```
Public sub Show_My_Userform()
userform1.Show
End Sub
```

The code written in `book1.xlsx`

```
Sub Workbook_open()
Application.Run "'book2.xlsx'!Show_My_Userform"
End sub
```

Here I have set reference in destination excel file but i actually want have the code to be written in the same `book2.xlsx`

Please help me in writing the code in the same workbook(`book2.xlsx`)

Comment: it is " 'book2.xlsx'!Show_My_Userform"

Comment: Eagerly waiting for the response

Comment: Was that a difficult question and yet why no one has recognized it